# Why does the unsubdivide function make face into diamonds?

Tags: modeling

[image]

This is not a question about the unsubdivide function in the decimate.
This is the question in the right mouse click menu.
Isn't un-sudvide a function of combining faces?
Why does face merge in diamond form?
Instead of a square.

[image]

Comment: As you can see, the [_Subdivide_ rules](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/subdivide.html) 
 are quite complicated, and _Unsubdivide_ according to the manual. 'Attempts to reverse them' . A regular grid seems to dissolve checker-deselected vertices, odd iterations resulting in diamonds, even iterations resulting in bigger squares, also depending on odd/even loop count, before boundaries are hit.
.

Comment: Not an answer, but consider looking at result of limited dissolve on second screen shot. @RobinBetts in my experience it "works" best for manifold geometry, eg can get the sub'd cube original back after apply, not the grid.

Comment: Sometimes it helps if you increase the Iterations to 2. (Left-bottom corner).

Comment: ah.. it is so hard. yep. can i get source code?